# MySql show 'no' if NULL, or 'yes' if not null

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IFNULL(Col,'b') FROM Table
```

Checks Col and returns Col if is not null if not it returns b.

How do I check Col, and return 'a' if not null or 'b' if null.

I tried this:

```
SELECT IF(Col=NULL,'a','b') FROM Table
```

Which always returns 'b'. How is this done?

Comment: see this manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `IS NULL` to check whether a column is null, instead of `= NULL`.

Every value compares with `NULL` the result will be `NULL`, so you will always get `b`.

```
SELECT IF(Col IS NULL,'a','b') FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing null values use `IS` instead of `=`

```
SELECT IF(Col IS NULL,'a','b') 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI SQL-92 compatible `CASE` statement wich works on all DBMS's instead of the proprietary `IF` statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Col IS NULL THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS Col
FROM   Table
```

Your current statement isn't working as expected because you can not compare `NULL` by using the `=` sign, you have to use `IS NULL` instead.

You might want to read up on [Three Valued Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29)

> Since Null is not a member of any data domain, it is not considered a
>   "value", but rather a marker (or placeholder) indicating the absence
>   of value. Because of this, comparisons with Null can never result in
>   either True or False, but always in a third logical result, Unknown